# Visual Studio 22 - Resharper - Cannot move line down

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

I am using Visual Studio 22 with ReSharper. I am trying to move a line of code down, and out of a block. ReSharper refuses to move the line down.

---

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if (true)
    {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl; // move this line down
    }
    // want the "done" line here, outside of the block
}
```

---

I've tried the ReSharper keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Down, which did not work.
[image: Visual Studio settings screen for keyboard shortcuts. Shows that Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Down is bound to ReSharper Move Down]

---

I also tried moving it down via the toolbar menu, which did not work.

*Extension -> ReSharper -> Edit -> Rearrange Code -> Move Down*

[image: Moving line down via the ReSharper menu under extensions.]

---

**How can I move this line down using a ReSharper keyboard shortcut, ideally.**

Comment: Afaik ReSharper doesn't work with C++,  you need to install ReSharperC++.

Comment: @273K You're right. I had plain ReSharper installed. I now installed ReSharper C++. The problem persists however.

Answer (score 0):

With ReSharper you need to use `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Left` to move a statement outside a block and `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Right` to move it inside. When you hold `Ctrl+Shift+Alt` ReSharper will show you the available directions to move the current element to.